# Parsing values with arguments while using Select

Tags: c#, windows

I have a rather simple question, but I haven't been able to solve it for a while now, even after googling. I have the following command that I would like to execute:

```
var dataFragments = bufferLine.Split(';').Select(double.Parse).ToList();
```

However I need the parsing to happen with the InvariantCulture. I would like to only use the invariant culture for this operation, but I haven't been able to figure out how I can set the appropriate arguments for this issue.

Here is an example for the data I want to parse:

```
1;-0.002;-0.005;0.994;-0.975;2.560;4.024;-2.700;3.299;86.699;1009.599;28.67;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the overload of `double.Parse` which takes an `IFormatProvider`, which `CultureInfo` implements:

```
var dataFragments = bufferLine.Split(';').Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```